# How to know the URL of a current Navigator

Tags: url, process, navigator

You are about to read many grammatical mistakes, sorry, I am not native to English language.

Hello, I am developing a simple software that counts the time you spend on applications, at the begin wasn't complicated, but now they request me to identify when the application is a navigator like Chrome, Firefox or IE. Then it has to identify what URL is currently in use to start count how much the user waste on all the open pages, but I don't know how to identify if is a navigator, obviously which URL is on it.

**OUTPUT EXAMPLE (output.txt)**

```
Process Used:    
netbeans 00:04:43     <- Done
calc 00:23:12     <- Done
chrome(www.facebook.com) 00:01:02    <- Dont know how
chrome(www.9gag.com) 00:17:23     <- Dont know how
```

**Global**

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

**This is the way i get the current process name that is in use**

```
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
            String NOMBRE = p.ProcessName.ToString();
```

Hope some can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Really no easy answers. "Navigators" are called web browsers, to help you in searching.

For the OS, they are regular programs, nothing special. In particular, the OS has no idea about the URL currently shown. That's a good thing, btw - the introduction of tabbed browsing means that you often have multiple tabs and thus multiple URLs open at the same time. If the OS knew about "the URL" of a webbrowser, it would have had major issues with tabbed browsing.

A good idea is to compare the URL in a webbrowser with the current score in a game. Both are simple variables, conceptually, but the OS doesn't try to track game scores either.

You can of course implement such a thing per type of webbrowser, but it takes work.